# Spoofing 500 Errors

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error, spoofing

I've recently designed a custom 500 error page (as the one for Wordpress solutions is pretty nasty to look at). In this new custom error page I have placed a retry button that links to a JS function to reload the requested page.

In order to test this I'm wondering if it's possible to 'spoof' 500 errors, i.e temporarily deliberately make the server show the 500 internal server error page, without there actually being an issue or causing any damage to the site itself.

I've searched on StackOverflow (no related topics) and Google but all posts related to 500 errors are to do with solving or fixing them rather than causing them (which makes sense but is of no use to me).

Any help in temporarily spoofing 500 errors (Wordpress) would be appreciated :)

Comment: Throw an exception from a random page?

Comment: i don't know a proper way to do this yet, but here i can simulate a 500 with a simple forgotten round bracket in a `if`. Try to add this line to a page: `if(true{ }`. Maybe it depends on server config, but works here (messing with htaccess can work too)

Comment: @Kaddath thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to backup core files and then mess with htaccess and wp-config to see if I can break it in the right way :)